# How to obtain the lagged monthly average value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a data like this: Where total_percentage_sale is the percentage sale of a product within the time period.

```
date.       product      sale   total_percentage_sale
2019-01-01.  productA.   12.    30
2019-01-01.  productB.   10.    25
2019-02-01.  productC.   8.     20
2019-02-01.  productD.   10.    25
```

I would like to obtain the lagged monthy average from the total_percentage_sale column.

Comment: Do you mean for a particular `year/month group` what's the `average` of `total_percentage_sale`?

Comment: For a aparticular month. The average for the total percentage sale is 25, but the avergae for january is 27.5 and for feb is 22.5

Answer (score -1):

**STEPS:**

1. First convert the `data-type of the` date.`column to`datetime`.
2. Extract the `year/month` using `.dt.date /.dt.month` respectively.
3. Use the extracted value to make the required groups and aggregate the `total_percentage_sale` column with the `mean` function to get the required output

```
df['date.'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date.'].str.strip('.'))
df.groupby([df['date.'].dt.year.values , df['date.'].dt.month.values]).agg({'total_percentage_sale' : 'mean'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
            total_percentage_sale
2019    1   27.5
        2   22.5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this much simpler approach which returns the monthly average of desired column -

```
df.groupby(['date'], sort=True)['total_percentage_sale'].mean()
```